# Can Gun Runner's Arsenal Mods be attached to any weapon in Fallout New Vegas

Tags: pc, mods, fallout-new-vegas

I brought a couple of Mods for an Anti-Material Rifle and they have a `(Gun Runners Arsenal)` label in the Pipboy but i can attach the mods, i did pick up the gun in a location that was added via a Quest Mod that i installed but i'm wondering whether i need a weapon with the same `(Gun Runners Arsenal)` label on it to equip these mods or if it's because this Quest Mod added an Anti-Material Rifle which is different from the regular one

Comment: Could you edit in the name and a link to the webpage of the Quest mod you installed?

Comment: @galacticninja no can do, i dont remember which Mod it is or exactly where i got it from, i know it was from a Nexus Site and i think the Mobile VaultTech Trailer (or close to that), it's not so much a quest mod but considering the amount of work you have to do to unlock the trailer without using the unlock console command i could see it as a quest (unlike the Underground Vault where the Quest was very simple and could be skipped when you enter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Fallout Wikia states that [some GRA mods can be used with non-GRA weapons](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gun_Runners%27_Arsenal#Weapon_modifications), I cannot find any mod that actually fits the description. This means that *all* the GRA weapon mods require GRA weapons.

Edit: I just tested the GRA Assault Carbine Extended Mags mod on the normal version of Assault Carbine and it didn't even come up in the Mods screen.

Comment: that's about the same response it get with my rifle, the only GRA mods i've used are for the Katana and i ended up buying one with the same GRA label on it

Answer (score 0):

Actually not all do. There are mods for guns such as varmit rifles and laser rifles and hunting rifles that arent gra weapons. If the weapon has a copy that is (GRA) then you can only put it on the gra copy.